# minimize json size by excluding fields with expected default values

Tags: serialization, gson

I have a class with several int, long and double fields.
I am trying to find a way to prevent gson from serialising fields with default values. For example, prevent serialising field A when it has the value 0, field B when it has the value 1 and field C when it has the value 2.

I looked at gson exclusion strategies, however these are for excluding fields based on their types or names. I need to exclude fields based on their actual values, which are of course dynamic.

Can this be done in gson?

Answer (score 0):

Gson does not have a specific built-in mechanism to handle this.  Custom serialization processing would be necessary.